# A3 Paper landscape in A4 portrait document with same headers and footers KOMA

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, landscape, paper-size

I need to have 1 A3 Page in a A4 Portrait document and I want the header and the footer to look the same, to have the same margin, to be on the same height etc and as well to center the footer. However I don't know how to do it....

[image: This is my regular document]
[image: This page is A3 landscape and header and footer should look alike than rest of the document]

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs,tabularx}\let\addLS\addlinespace
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{paralist,dcolumn,ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{makecell, rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Tabellenabstand einstellen
\usepackage{cellspace}
\addtolength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\addtolength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\title{Aufgabenstellung FRAISA Pro3MMb}



\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Kopfzeile erstellen
\lhead{Vorrichtung zur reproduzierbaren Verschleissdokumentation}
\chead{}
\rhead{Modul Pro3MMb}

%Fusszeile erstellen
%\lfoot{Harre, Burkhard, Schläpfer, Wyss}
\cfoot{FHNW}
\rfoot{\thepage \ von \pageref{LastPage}} % \thepage aktuelle Seite (Seitenzahl)

% Höhe Kopf- und Fusszeile
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}    % Trennlinien Oben einfügen
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Trennlinien unten einfügen



\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{Roman}

\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents

\section{Sitzungsprotokolle}


\section{Pflichtenheft}
NOCH MIT UNTERSCHRIFT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}
\section{Zeitplan}
\vspace*{2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Bastle/zeitplan.PNG}

\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=portrait,DIV=calc}




\newpage

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use package `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-Script class.

But if you have to use `fancyhdr`, you have to add eg. `\fancyheadoffset{0pt}` to ensure that the position of header and footer width will be recalculated.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}% <- added

\lhead{Vorrichtung zur reproduzierbaren Verschleissdokumentation}
\chead{}
\rhead{Modul Pro3MMb}
\cfoot{FHNW}
\rfoot{\thepage \ von \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Sitzungsprotokolle}
\section{Pflichtenheft}
NOCH MIT UNTERSCHRIFT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

\cleardoubleoddpage
\storeareas\normalpapersize% <- save the page layout
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}
\section{Zeitplan}
\vspace*{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\normalpapersize% <- restore the page layout
Weiterer Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage` (part of the KOMA-Script bundle):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\ihead{Vorrichtung zur reproduzierbaren Verschleissdokumentation}
\chead{}
\ohead{Modul Pro3MMb}
\cfoot{FHNW}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage \ von \pageref{LastPage}}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Sitzungsprotokolle}
\section{Pflichtenheft}
NOCH MIT UNTERSCHRIFT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

\cleardoubleoddpage
\storeareas\normalpapersize% <- save the page layout
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}
\section{Zeitplan}
\vspace*{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\normalpapersize% <- restore the page layout
Weiterer Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the margins should be the same even on the A3 paper you could use:

```latex
\documentclass[usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\newcommand\changepapersize[1]{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \KOMAoption{paper}{#1}%
  \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}%
  \newgeometry{margin=2.5cm}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\storeareas\normalpapersize}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\cleardoubleoddpage}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\ihead{Vorrichtung zur reproduzierbaren Verschleissdokumentation}
\chead{}
\ohead{Modul Pro3MMb}
\cfoot{FHNW}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage \ von \pageref{LastPage}}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Sitzungsprotokolle}
\section{Pflichtenheft}
NOCH MIT UNTERSCHRIFT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

\changepapersize{A3,landscape}
\section{Zeitplan}
\vspace*{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\normalpapersize
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional remarks:

- Package `inputenc` with option `utf8` is only needed with older TeX distributions.
- Package `tikz` loads i.a. `xcolor`, `color`, `graphicx`, `rotating` automatically.
- Package `tabularx` loads package `array` automatically.
- Do not load package `booktabs` twice.
- Package `hyperref` should be loaded after the other packages. There are only a few documented exceptions.
- Before you change the page numbering system (`\pagenumbering{...}`} use a `\cleardoublepage` or `\cleardoubleoddpage` to ensure that odd page numbers on right pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, really solved it! And thanks for the additional remarks!!