# A3 paper landscape in A4 portrait document with same margins

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script, geometry, landscape

I want to have some A3 landscape pages in my A4 portrait document. These should have the same margins as the A4 pages. I tried the solution of  [A3 Paper landscape in A4 portrait document with same headers and footers KOMA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579694/a3-paper-landscape-in-a4-portrait-document-with-same-headers-and-footers-koma) but this didn´t work for me. Here is an example of my code and the result I get:

```
\documentclass[11pt,            % Schriftgröße
a4paper,                        % Papierformat
oneside,                        % einseitiges (oneside) oder zweiseitiges (twoside) Dokument
listof=totoc,                   % Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
bibliography=totoc,             % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
titlepage,                      % Titlepage-Umgebung statt \maketitle
headsepline,                    % horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel
%abstracton,                    % Überschrift beim Abstract einschalten, Abstract muss dazu in {abstract}-Umgebung stehen
DIV18,                          % auskommentieren, um den Seitenspiegel zu vergrößern
BCOR6mm,                        % Bindekorrektur, die den Seitenspiegel um 6mm nach rechts verschiebt,
cleardoublepage=empty,          % Stil einer leeren eingefügten Seite bei Kapitelwechsel
parskip                         % Absatzabstand bei Absatzwechsel einfügen
xcolor=dvipsnames,
pointlessnumbers                %verhindert Punkt in Beschriftung (Abbildung 1.1.:) 
]{scrbook}  
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}         
\usepackage{ucs}                % Dokument in utf8-Codierung schreiben und speichern
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % ermöglicht die direkte Eingabe von Umlauten
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Trennungsregeln und Übersetzung der festcodierten Überschriften
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Ausgabe aller zeichen in einer T1-Codierung (wichtig für die Ausgabe von Umlauten!)
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}     % bei neuem Abschnitt nicht einrücken
\linespread{1.2}\selectfont     % Zeilenabstand erhöhen - größere Werte als 1.2 nicht verwenden!!
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}   % SCR Headings verwenden
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}          % Kopfzeile Linien oben
\setfootsepline{0.4pt}          % Kopfzeile Linien unten
\pagestyle{scrheadings}         % SCR Headings einschalten
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Einbinden von Grafiken erlauben

%---
\newcommand\changepapersize[1]{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \KOMAoption{paper}{#1}%
  \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}%
  \newgeometry{margin=2.5cm}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\storeareas\normalpapersize}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\cleardoubleoddpage}
%---

\begin{document}  


\chapter{Chapter}

\clearpage
\section{Section}

\changepapersize{A3,landscape}
Here stands some random text. This page is in format A3, landscape. And here comes an huge image:

\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{image.jpg}

\normalpapersize
This page is in format A4, portrait.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You have to add class option `usegeometry` and to remove the outdated `\setheadsepline` and `\setfootline` macros. Use the `scrlayer-scrpage` options `headsepline=<line width>` and `footsepline=<line width>`. Note that `0.4pt` is the default line width.

Additional remarks:

- `11pt`, `a4paper` and `cleardoublepage=empty` are default options
- use `DIV=18`, `BCOR=6mm` and `numbers=pointless` to replace depracted options
- packages `ucs` and `inputenc` only needed with a really outdated latex version
- package `scrlayer-scrpage` sets page style `scrheadings` automatically

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
%11pt,% default
%a4paper,% default
oneside,
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
titlepage,
%DIV=18,% syntax corrected
BCOR=6mm,% syntax corrected
usegeometry,% <- added!
%cleardoublepage=empty,% default
parskip,% comma added
numbers=pointless% syntax corrected
]{scrbook}  
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}         
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.2}\selectfont     % Zeilenabstand erhöhen - größere Werte als 1.2 nicht verwenden!!
\usepackage[
  headsepline,% or headsepline=<line width>, 0.4pt is default
  footsepline,% or footsepline=<line width>, 0.4pt is default
  plainfootsepline% footsepline on plain pages too
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% enables pagestyle
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\changepapersize[1]{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \KOMAoption{paper}{#1}%
  \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}%
  \newgeometry{margin=2.5cm}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\storeareas\normalpapersize}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\cleardoubleoddpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\clearpage
\section{Section}

\changepapersize{A3,landscape}
Here stands some random text. This page is in format A3, landscape. And here comes an huge image:

\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}

\normalpapersize
This page is in format A4, portrait.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank`s a lot, it worked!